# use a string array without CREATE privileges

Tags: oracle, cursors, user-defined-type, user-defined-table-type

I have a set of tables where I need to determine if a particular set of about 1000 row IDs are present in one specific field in each table.

```
select 'Accounts', row_id Acct_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_org_ext
where pr_postn_id in ('1-ABCD','1-BCDE')
UNION
select 'Orders', row_id Order_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_orders
where pr_postn_id in ('1-ABCD','1-BCDE')
```

The above works well for two row_ids, but copy/pasting the `IN` clause for 1000 IDs is unwieldy when I need to update the list, especially as the list appears in each `IN` clause on ten `UNION`-ed queries.

I am looking for an array or a string variable to use in the `IN` clause and refer to that variable or array in the subsequent queries, in the form `UNION SELECT ... WHERE id IN`  *some kind of huge list of VARCHAR2 IDs* .

Normally I would just create a table but in this system I'm a business analyst, not a dba. CREATE privileges won't be happening for me. If I do try create anything in the database, I get

```
[Error] Compilation (2: 1): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I've tried to use a DECLARE block with cursor, but with no success (no  privilege violations, just faulty SQL code)

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE posrec_t IS RECORD (
    pos_row_id VARCHAR2(15) );
    TYPE poslist IS TABLE OF posrec; 
    todaypos poslist :=
      poslist (
      posrec ('1-103KO-18'),posrec ('1-10TOV-1'));
    posrec posrec_t;
    

CURSOR MYCURSOR IS select 'Opportunity' Data_Object, row_id Data_object_Id, pr_postn_id
from siebel.s_oppor
WHERE PR_POSTN_ID IN posrec
UNION 
[etc]
BEGIN
OPEN MYCURSOR;
END;
```

With the `DECLARE BEGIN END` block syntax, it seems like I could create a short-lived temporary table of 1000 IDs that appear once as a definition statement (and without needing `CREATE` rights), but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I cannot see why you would not have CREATE TABLE privilege in your own schema. It is not a DBA type privilege. Have you asked for it?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett Even our own schemas for our IDs has no CREATE.  It's the decades-old policy of both my employer and the contractor managing the systems.  I would have to be approved as an exception for roles that are unusual in my organization.  I'll pass on that; I already create enough trouble.  But it also appears I have workarounds now.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Albert Godfrind's answer, but there's a built-in type, SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL, that has a PUBLIC privilege that can be used. The following code sample should give you an idea on usage

```
declare
   v_tab1 SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL := SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('ONE','TWO','THREE');
   v_tab2 SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL := SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('TWO','THREE');
   v_cnt  number;
begin
   select count(*)
   into v_cnt
   from table(v_tab1)
   where column_value not in (select column_value from table(v_tab2));
end;
/
```

Comment: sys.odcivarchar2list seems to do something similar but is a bit better documented, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

1. Create a string array type:

```
create or replace type string_array as varray(1000) of varchar2(10);
/
```

2. Use that in a `with` clause to construct the list of values as a virtual table, and use that table in your query, like this:

```
with t as (
  select column_value as code from table(string_array('1-ABCD','1-BCDE',...))
)
select 'Accounts', row_id Acct_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_org_ext
where pr_postn_id in (select code from t)
UNION
select 'Orders', row_id Order_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_orders
where pr_postn_id in (select code from t)
UNION
...
```

Comment: Not sure that the user has rights to create a type in their own schema.

Comment: True that. I actually started by using the `SDO_STRING_ARRAY` type, that is very much like the one I proposed creating. This comes with the Spatial feature and unless a DBA has explicitly removed it from the database, it should be present. So replace `string_array('1-ABCD','1-BCDE',...)` with `sdo_string_array('1-ABCD','1-BCDE',...)` and Wistlo should be all set.

Comment: And a `describe sdo_string_array` will confirm whether it is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't create anything, your only option is to explicitly write the list of IDs. To avoid repeating it, you could put it into a common table expression:

```
with params (id) as (
  select '1-ABCD' from dual union all 
  select '1-BCDE' from dual union all 
  ....
  select '999-XYZ' from dual
)  
select 'Accounts', row_id Acct_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_org_ext
where pr_postn_id in (select id from params)
UNION ALL
select 'Orders', row_id Order_id, pr_postn_id
from schema.s_orders
where pr_postn_id in (select id from params)
```

As Oracle still doesn't support a VALUES clause, you need to write many lines of `select ... from dual` to union all values together - but at least you only need to write it once.

Creating a spreadsheet that generates the `select .. from dual union all ... select` for your (based on the "plain values", might make maintaining this list a bit easier. Then copy & paste the generated values from the spreadsheet into the WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write a program, say in Python, that generates the SQL for you. It could read a file with your list of ids and generate the SQL statement with the ids repeated however many times they are needed.